# Redirect Url after success response from server

Tags: php, json, redirect

I am using php to make a GET Request. After the response it must redirect me to response URL, but I do not know to do it. The response is in json format, like this:

`{"orderId":"308fea18-9288-460e-8c24-e2******","formUrl":"https://test.bank.com/payment/merchants/payment.html?mdOrder=308fea18-e2c68d9d3a2e&language=en"}`

This response is after success payment request and redirects me to a page with card information.

Here is form request:

```
<form name="PaymentForm" action="https://test.bank.com/payment/register.do" method="GET" id="formPayment">
<input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userName" value="api">
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="api2">
<input type="hidden" name="orderNumber" id="orderNumber" value="00000116">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" name="description" id="description" value="description">
<input type="hidden" name="language" id="language" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="pageView" id="pageView" value="DESKTOP">
<input type="hidden" name="clientId" id="clientId" value="2">

//a button for payment confirmation
<input value="Изпрати" type="submit" id="buttonPayment" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
</form>
```

How to redirect users automatically after success request?

I searched through many links but somehow could not solve my problem.

Now i tried to send data with ajax, but i catch other error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.bank.com/payment/register.do?[object%20FormData]' from origin 'http://site.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

here is a ajax:

```
 $( "#buttonPayment" ).click(function() {
    var modal = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://ecomtest.dskbank.bg/payment/rest/register.do",
        crossDomain: true,
        method: "GET",
        data: new FormData($('#formPayment')[0]), // The form with the file inputs.
        processData: false, // Using FormData, no need to process data.
        contentType: false, // Using FormData, no need to process data.
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The keyword is Ajax. You make the request via JavaScript in the users browser. Then you check its return value and do other stuff. (For example redirect a user to a new page if the payment was successful)

Comment: and i must send parametrs with Ajax and in success to try the catch the response?

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode first your json object and then get the url.

```
<?php
$json = '{"orderId":"308fea18-9288-460e-8c24-e2******","formUrl":"https://test.bank.com/payment/merchants/payment.html?mdOrder=308fea18-e2c68d9d3a2e&language=en"}';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json); //Decode the json object
$url = $json_decoded->formUrl; //Get the url
header("Location: $url"); //Pass the url into redirection
```

Comment: yes, but the response is on users browser and i can not catch the answer response with post method ... maybe paskl is right with ajax ....

Comment: What do you mean by users browser ? Can you add more information to your question

Comment: on other domain (on the bank domain, not redirect me to my application)

Comment: You want to add your code into another website ? What is the purpose

Comment: i do not know how, i must catch the response and for that i am asking ... by the institution only say that must be a script ...

Comment: You have to check the API of the bank

Comment: _“yes, but the response is on users browser”_ - seems like you did not use this in the way it is intended in the first place. You are most likely supposed to make this first request from the server, not the client. Then you decode the JSON response, and redirect the user to that second URL in their browser.